# Index page not rendering but downloads csv

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, export-to-csv

I am working on a rails app which reads the JSON data then creates a CSV from that data. The issue I am facing is the CSV download works perfectly fine but the index page doesn't show.

When I go to localhost:3000 the CSV is downloaded but index.html.erb page is not rendered. Please help me find the issue where I am going wrong.

controller.rb

```
def index
  csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|

    file = JSON.parse(File.open("app/assets/javascripts/data.json").read)
    @data = file
    new_file = @data.sort_by!{ |m| m["name"] }
    new_file.each do |hash|
      hash['name'] = (hash.values[2])
      hash['city'] = (hash.values[3])
    end
  end
  send_data csv_data, type: :csv
end
```

routes.rb

```
root :to => "name#index"
```

index.html.erb

```
<h1 align="center">File is downloaded</h1>
```

if I add the code below in the controller index action then the html is rendered but the download csv stops working.

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html
 format.csv { send_data csv_data, type: :csv }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add html format as respond format:

```
def index
  csv_data = ..
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.csv { send_data csv_data }
  end
end
```

Comment: I have already tried this. In this case, the HTML is rendered but CSV download doesn't work.

Comment: @Navroop doesn't download when you add `.csv` to the end of url?

Comment: it doesn't give any error. it's just that HTML is rendered and CSV download doesn't work.

Comment: add this code to index.html.erb and try to click it?: `<%= link_to "Download CSV", your_index_path(format: :csv) %>`

Comment: Yes, in that case, HTML is rendered and CSV is downloaded when clicked on the link. But I want it should be downloaded with the URL.

Comment: You should add `.csv` to your url. For example your url is: `localhost:3000/books`, you should enter  `localhost:3000/books.csv` to browser.

Comment: Right now when I click the button to download the CSV this is the URL which shows up http://localhost:3000/?format=csv

Comment: Won't it work with just  **localhost:3000** as the url?

Comment: No, it does not work with **localhost:3000**. It shows index view.

Comment: If you want to download datas as csv, you need to specify the format.

Comment: Is there any way when the user enters the localhost:3000 then user is automatically redirected to http://localhost:3000/?format=csv

Comment: I misunderstood you. You want both the index view and download same time?

Comment: I'm not sure, **send_data** may solve your problem. Try it this way: send_data csv_data, type: 'text/csv', disposition: 'attachment', filename: 'csv_data.csv'

Answer (score 0):

**1/ Extract your `CSV` logic in a private method:**

```
def download_csv
  csv_data = CSV.generate do |csv|
    file = JSON.parse(File.open("app/assets/javascripts/data.json").read)
    @data = file
    new_file = @data.sort_by!{ |m| m["name"] }
    new_file.each do |hash|
      hash['name'] = (hash.values[2])
      hash['city'] = (hash.values[3])
    end
  end
  send_data csv_data, type: :csv
end
```

**2/ Call your private method inside `before_action`:**

`before_action :download_csv, only: :index`

**3/ Update your route to set `html` by default (*maybe not necessary*):**

`root :to => "name#index", defaults: { format: 'html' }`

Basically calling `send_file/send_data` from a before action will not halt the request cycle, because it doesn't use `render` or `redirect_to`.

I hope it helps.

**__Edited answer__**

Actually I guess is not a regular comportement to render multiple routes for one `action`. And I think you should find another way to achieve this. I recommend you the following code (from my first solution):

**1/ Add a specific route to download**

`get '/name/download_csv', to: "name#download_csv"`

**2/ Add some Jquery in your view**

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    window.location.href = 'name/download_csv.csv';
  })
</script>
```

**3/ Remove the `private` reserved word from your controller**

In this way each time you go to your `index view` you are going to call your `download` action throughout `Jquery`. 
It's not really "rails way" but it should works.

Let me know if it works.

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't render the index.html.erb it just downloads the CSV but HTML is not rendered